# TensorFlow: Add dimension (column) with constant value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensor of shape `(-1,)` which represents a list of indices. I want to create a Tensor of shape `(-1,2)`. The first column should be the same as the list of indices, while the second column should be filled with a constant.

Eg (let's say the constant is 6):

```
indices = [4, 35, 230, 235]
my_goal = [[4, 6], [35, 6], [230, 6], [235, 6]]
```

What is the best way to do this? I was hoping a broadcasting-`tf.concat` would work, but `tf.concat` doesn't seem to support broadcasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tensorflow.pad`. But first you have to make it a two dimensional tensor.

```
indices = tf.constant([1,2,3,4])
indices = tf.expand_dims(tf, 1)  # now you have a (4,1) tensor
padding = [[0,0],[0,1]] # no padding before or after the first dimension
                        # no padding before second dimension. Single-element padding
                        # after the second dimension
my_goal = tf.pad(indices, padding, constant_values=6)
```

Padding has to be [n,2] tensor. For more information, look into: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad.